# Accessing argument values for argparse in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to set up some simple flag arguments for my program but cannot figure out how to access them.  I have the argparser:

```
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple PostScript Interpreter')
   parser.add_argument('-s', action="store_true")
   parser.add_argument('-d', action="store_true")
   parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

The program should take either `sps.py -s`, `sps.py -d`, or `sps.py` on the command line. Then I just want to check whether or not the `-s` flag was set or the `-d` flag was set. If neither were set, then just default to -d.

What do I need to do to access the boolean values that are set by the parser?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't need to give [`parse_args()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) any parameters. You call it like this:

```
>>> args = parser.parse_args()
```

which will return a [`NameSpace`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) object. You can access your arguments using the dot notation:

```
>>> args.s
False

>>> args.d
False
```

Working example:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple PostScript Interpreter')
parser.add_argument('-s', action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-d', action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

Running it like so:

```
msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ python sps.py
Namespace(d=False, s=False)

msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ python sps.py -d
Namespace(d=True, s=False)

msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ python sps.py -s
Namespace(d=False, s=True)
```

Comment: when I do that and enter `sps.py -d` it says `error: unrecognized arguments: -d`

Comment: Running `python sps.py -d` or `-s` works fine for me with your code, when I remove the `sys.argv[1:]` from `parse_args()`. How exactly are you running this?

Comment: i took out the sys.argv[1:] as well. I got it working, but I had to keep the add_argument() calls for both -d and -s. After doing that, the Namespace obj was created correctly

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, the only part where you had a problem with the code was the `sys.argv[1:]` which would've resulted in weird option values. You *do* need to have the `add_argument()` for any command line argument you wish to implement. Perhaps I should've talked about function arguments, or parameters instead of just arguments to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks so much @msvalkon for this answer, I spent forever looking through the docs, and missed the section on the namespace class (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object). This is a super helpful answer!

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.s
print args.d
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code is mostly correct:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple PostScript Interpreter')
parser.add_argument('-s', action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-d', action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

although the default argument to `parse_args` makes passing `sys.argv[1:]` unnecessary. Since each argument is parsed independently, you'll need a post-processing step after the arguments are parsed:

```
if not args.s and not args.d:
    args.s = True
```