# TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not Namespace

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.9, PyCharm 2022.

My purpose (Ultimate goal of this question): create a command line application receive 2 parameters:

- Path of directory
- Extension of files

then get size of files (Per file size, not sum of files size).

```py
import os
import argparse
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("path", help="Path of directory.")
    parser.add_argument("ext", help="Extension of files (for example: jpg, png, exe, mp4, etc.")
    args1 = parser.parse_args()
    args2 = parser.parse_args()
    print(args1)
    arr = os.listdir(args1)
    print(arr)
    # os.path.getsize(args.path)

    # bytes_size = os.path.getsize(args1.path)
    # mb_size = int(bytes_size / 1024 / 1024)
    # print(mb_size, "MB")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My command and according error:

```py
(base) PS C:\Users\donhu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4> python size.py 'D:' 'jpg'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\donhu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\size.py", line 22, in <module>
(base) PS C:\Users\donhu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4> python size.py 'D:' 'jpg'
Namespace(path='D:', ext='jpg')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\donhu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\size.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\donhu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\size.py", line 13, in main
    arr = os.listdir(args1)
TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not Namespace
(base) PS C:\Users\donhu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4>
```

[image]
How to fix?

Update, I tried something

```py
import os
import argparse
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from pathlib import *

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("path", help="Đường dẫn của thư mục")
    parser.add_argument("ext", help="Định dạng tập tin cần liệt kê kích thước.")
    args1 = parser.parse_args()
    args2 = parser.parse_args()
    foo = args1.path

    # arr = os.listdir('D:/')
    files = [x for x in foo.iterdir() if x.is_file()]
    print(files)
    # os.path.getsize(args.path)

    # bytes_size = os.path.getsize(args1.path)
    # mb_size = int(bytes_size / 1024 / 1024)
    # print(mb_size, "MB")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but not work.

Comment: `args1 = parser.parse_args()` followed by `args2 = parser.parse_args()` is just parsing the command line twice. You get two [argparse.Namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) objects, both with the same data.

Comment: one of parts ok. The next step, `ttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_file'` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `os` module holds the traditional interface into the file system. It closely follows the Clib interface so you'll see functions like `listdir` and `stat`. `pathlib` is a new object oriented "pythonic" interface to the file system. One can argue whether its better, but I use it, so its gotta be, right?

It looks like you are mixing "old" and "new" ways of doing things, which gets confusing. If you want to use `pathlib`, try to use it for everything.

Here is your script re-imagined for pathlib. You only need to parse the command line once and then build a `Path` object for the directory of interest.

```
import argparse
from pathlib import Path

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("path", help="Đường dẫn của thư mục")
    parser.add_argument("ext", help="Định dạng tập tin cần liệt kê kích thước.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    foo = Path(args.path)
    if not foo.is_dir():
        print("Error: Must be a directory")
        exit(1)
    files = [x for x in foo.iterdir() if x.is_file()]
    print(files)
    # os.path.getsize(args.path)
    bytes_size = sum(file.stat().st_size for file in files)
    print("total bytes", bytes_size)
    # mb_size = int(bytes_size / 1024 / 1024)
    # print(mb_size, "MB")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you want to use the `ext` parameter, you would change from `iterdir` to glob.

```
files = [x for x in foo.glob(f"*.{args.ext}") if x.is_file()]
```

or

```
files = [x for x in foo.glob(f"**/*.{args.ext}") if x.is_file()]
```

depending on whether you want just the directory or its subtree.

Comment: Still not filter file extension as second argument. https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/0de84456331a4895bb19f5dbacec8fdb

Comment: @JamesGrey - Just added that. it wasn't in the original script so I put it in as an addendum.

Answer (score 0):

Argparse's `parse_args()` function returns a `Namespace` object. I believe your goal was to pass the `path` argument, you have to access it as an attribute.

```
os.listdir(args1.path)
```

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/205474682-14772047-11fe-49e5-9aae-819b1d2445d5.png Please focus on question. I need getting value from application's arguments, not list files/folders.

Comment: I cannot use `args1.path` for `args1.path.iterdir()`

Comment: What is `iterdir()`?  That is not mentioned anywhere in the question...

Comment: `os.listdir(args1.path)` does address your question.  But it seems you have a different one in mind...

Comment: @JamesGrey `args1.path` is a string, if you want to iterate the directory that this string is referring to you need to convert it to a Path with `pathlib`. Regardless of your program's purpose, the error in the code is what I described above.

Comment: @JamesGrey - You are confusing two different ways to address the file system, `os` functions and `pathlib.Path`.

Comment: How to use application with argument D:\ then, assign all files (not directory) to an array? Everything happen for few reasons.

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/205474874-55861781-4994-4b08-8731-94f97d95d39c.png

Comment: Try `os.path.isdir(os.path.join(args1.path, x))`.

Answer (score 0):

Program

```py
import os
import argparse
from pathlib import Path


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("path", help="Path of directory/folder")
    parser.add_argument("ext", help="Extension of file what need get size.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    foo = Path(args.path)
    files = [x for x in foo.glob(f"*.{args.ext}") if x.is_file()]
    for file in files:
        print(file.__str__(), os.path.getsize(file))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    
# python size.py  "D:\"  'jpg'

# (base) PS C:\Users\donhu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4> python size.py  "D:\"  'jpg'
# D:\1496231_10152440570407564_3432420_o.jpg 241439
# D:\15002366_278058419262140_505451777021235_o.jpg 598063
# D:\1958485_703442046353041_1444502_n.jpg 63839
# D:\277522952_5065319530178162_680264454398630_n.jpg 335423
```

Answer (score -1):

Your two command line arguments are being returned as a single object of the argparse.Namespace class, both stored identically in your args1 and (the superfluous) args2 variables.
Inserting the following line after your calls to parse_args() and commenting out the subsequent code would illuminate this a little more:

```
print(type(args1))
```

To access the values you named in your calls to add_argument(), use this syntax:

```
args1.path
args1.ext
```

such as

```
arr = os.listdir(args1.path)
```

For further discussion, see this answer: [Accessing argument values for argparse in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069075/accessing-argument-values-for-argparse-in-python)